# why do I get shell: not found?

Tags: bash, shell

When I try to compile and run simple bash script.

```
export TEST_DRIVE=$(shell pwd)
echo $TEST_DRIVE
```

I get error **shell: not found**

comment:- I wanted to point out that I saw this on makefile.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik  actually saw this in make file and wanted to write simple test example... probably I am mixing bash script and make file.

Comment: yup - [`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) is a makefile command.

Comment: so if shell is make file command, shouldn't this script compile with shell then? ( sorry I am little confused here)

Comment: so ok this is a way makefile use to invoke shell command ?

Comment: shell scripts don't need to be compiled.

Comment: @twalberg thank you for the comment .. so we can say execute instead of compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `shell` isn't a command your system knows.

That's a valid `make` assignment though.

Did you mean `export TEST_DRIVE=$(pwd)`?

Comment: Thank you @Etan .. So what language is makefile written? isn't it in bash

Comment: No. Makefiles have their own syntax. The recipes of targets (within the makefile) are often shell scripts however.